# URL Rewriting for Dynamic Php Pages

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details.php?id=5 && name=Heading1
http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details.php?id=6 && name=Heading2
http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details.php?id=7 && name=Heading3
```

How to rewrite above URL like this

```
http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details/Heading1
http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details/Heading2
http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details/Heading3
```

Itried this code but it not work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ blog_details.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog_details.php [QSA,L]
```

Help me please, how to remove .php extenction and id,name from url using php and htaccess

Comment: `&& name=` err.. why 2x ampersands? That shouldn't even work in the first place.

Comment: What is the relation between `id` and `Heading1`? What about `http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details/5/Heading1`?

Comment: You should have to pass id also in rewritten URL as such it is dynamic. Like http://www.example.com/blog/blog_details/5/Heading1

Comment: id is corresponding table id and heading is corresponding  News heading

Comment: @chris85 and Rahul Patel any hope to remove 5 in URL

Comment: If you want to statically list every URL yes. Most people like dynamic rules though so you don't have a huge htaccess file, and so you arent updating that with every website update. Write out the whole `/blog/blog_details/Heading1` in a rule, then write the rewrite. Make sure to end the URL too, `$` or else `Heading1` will match `Heading12`, `Heading13`, etc.